# Passing parameter to the constructor of a generic Class type

Tags: c#, generics

I have written the code as below

```
public interface IScreenBuilder
{
        void Build<TBusinessLogic, TPresenter, TForm> (ILog logger) 
            where TPresenter : class, new()
            where TForm : class, new();        
}

public class ScreenBuilder: IScreenBuilder
{
    private ILog _logger;
    public void Build<TBusinessLogic, TPresenter, TForm>(ILog logger)
           where TPresenter : class, new()
            where TForm : class, new()
    {
        _logger = logger;
        TBusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogicBuilder().Build<TBusinessLogic>();
        TPresenter presenter = new TPresenter(businessLogic);
                TForm form = new TForm(presenter);
    }
}
```

I need to pass a parameter to the TPresenter and TForm. Is it possible for me to do this? If yes how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do that with just generic constraints. There is no generic constaint in the C# language that says the "type must have a constructor with a parameter of type X".

That means you can't create an object of the `TForm` class using `new TForm(presenter)`.

But - and that's the good news - it is still possible to do using reflection:

```
var type = typeof(TPresenter);
var constructor = type.GetConstructors()
                      .FirstOrDefault(c => 
                          (c.GetParameters().Count() == 1) &&
                          (c.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(TBusinessLogic)));

if (constructor == null)
{
    throw new SomeException();
}

TPresenter presenter = (TPresenter)constructor.Invoke(
    new object[]{ businessLogic });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the new() generic constraint only ensures that the types have a default parameterless constructor.  So your generic types don't know that they support a constructor that takes parameters.

Rather than passing in constructor parameters, you could ensure your types implement an interface that allows you to call a property or method e.g. Init(xxx), that allows you to pass in initial parameters after construction.  For example, you could could have a parameter called IInitialisable.  Then you make that a type constraint on your types.

Answer (score 0):

For TPresenter and TForm you can replace where TPresenter : class, new() with a actulal implementation or abstract class which contains parametrized constructor as below

```
     public void Build<TBusinessLogic, TPresenter, TForm>(ILog logger)
        where TPresenter : PresenterClass, new()
            where TForm : FormClass, new()
    {
        _logger = logger;
        TBusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogicBuilder().Build<TBusinessLogic>();
        TPresenter presenter = new TPresenter(10);
                TForm form = new TForm(20);
    } 

    public abstract class PresenterClass
    {
        public PresenterClass(int parm)
        {
        }
    }

    public abstract class FormClass
    {
        public FormClass(int parm)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Just because the base class has a constructor with 1 parameter doesn't mean that the concrete does will have the same.